# How do you manage three.js libraries?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a package manager for three.js extras?  Things like FlyControls or EffectComposer, is there a way to easily pull and include these files?  Right now i have to go into the examples for them and download the files from their source.  I'd love to use bower or something to pull them in with a single command.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the three.js build script

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/build

Comment: Could you explain? It looks like that's for building three.js from source which is something I don't think we want to do for every project

Comment: It's basically concatenate a list of js sources (the preferred files from whole three.js project that represent the most relevant part for your needs) and minimize it into one package file. You can adapt the three.js main package and added inside it another files like FlyControls. once you build it you can use it for all of yours project. i found this link that may help you more: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/build.py,-or-how-to-generate-a-compressed-Three.js-file

Comment: So i've been using grunt to do all my file concatenation, my question is, is there a repository for these files, or are people just always copying the files around between all their projects?